Updating the datagridview on the inactive form when the data on the active form changes
Can you please advise me on this solution?
I have a frame1 with a datagridview with a datatable source. In the background is a second inactive frame2 with a datagridview with a datatable source. How do I make sure that when I save the changes in the datagridview on frame1, the datagridview on frame2 is then automatically updated?
email@pavelmachek.cz
I tried something like this:
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgPlan.Rows
    For Each myForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If myForm.Text = row.Cells("Lis").Value.ToString Then
           Dim form As New Stroj(myForm.Text)
           form.MdiParent = Main
           form.Name = myForm.Text
           form.Text = myForm.Text
           form.fmOd.Value = Now.AddDays(-4).ToShortDateString
           form.fmDo.Value = Now.AddDays(40).ToShortDateString
           myForm.Close()
           form.Plan_Load(myForm.Text)
           form.Show()
        End If
    Next
Next


What is the relationship between the two forms? Did one create the other? If so, was the second form displayed using Show or ShowDialog? Do you want the inactive form to be updated as changes are made or only when the active form closes? Are both forms displaying the same data? If not, how is it related?
